# Bash variable being overwritten

Tags: bash, vagrant

I have the following script that is behaving very strangely:

```
#!/bin/bash
function getip()
{
  vagrant ssh $1 -c "ip address show eth1 | grep 'inet ' | sed -e 's/^.*inet //' -e 's/\/.*$//'"
}
node1=$(getip node1)
node2=$(getip node2)
echo $node1 $node2
```

What I am expecting to see is:

```
192.168.0.2 192.168.0.3
```

but what I'm actually seeing is:

```
 192.168.0.3
```

If I change the last line to be:

```
echo $node1
```

I then get:

```
192.168.0.2
```

My question is, what is going on here? I've found a few answers saying that this could be to do with subshells but I was under the impression that this would work if I used a function. Any ideas?

Comment: Same script just changing the last line to not include `$node2` and you get the `192.168.0.2` output?

Comment: There's also no reason to indirect through `result` like this. If you use `getip() { vagrant ssh ...; }` then you can use `node1=$(getip node1); node2=$(getip node2)`.

Comment: Instead of this elusive, non-included setup.sh, could you just `echo $node1 $node2`? If that works, it's just your setup.sh which is broken. BTW: I love Puppet or Chef or the like for setups instead of ssh calls ;)

Comment: @EtanReisner I've edited the script as you suggested but still get the same result

Comment: What do you get if you add `| hexdump -C` to the end of that `echo` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a CR at the end of the text in `$node1`. Strip it before outputting.